# Laravel routes with unlimited parameters for RESTful API

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel-5.1

I am building a RESTful API using Laravel 5.1. 
The default route would be `api`. The user is allowed to create a url service using as many as parameters as she wants let's say `.../api/p1/p2/.../pn`.

How do I make a single route to point to a single Controller, so the service will be handled in a single controller?

Note : At first the application just needs to know whether the service exists or not by comparing the `url` with stored service in the database. As for the service itself, it can be queried into the database later.

I read that we can use `*` in Laravel 4, how about Laravel 5.1 ?

I have tried :

`Route::resource('/api/*', 'APIServiceController');` but it does not work for unlimited parameters

or is it possible to do it like this

`Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    //what should I put in the closure, how can I redirect it to a single controller
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your route as below:-

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    // this route will basically catch everything that starts with api/routeName 
    Route::get('routeName/{params?}', function($params= null){
        return $params;
    })->where('params', '(.*)');
});
```

Redirect to controller,

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('routeName/{params?}', 'YourController@action')->where('params', '(.*)');
});
```

If you want to make routeName dynamic then just write it in curly bracket as below:-

```
Route::get('{routeName}/{params?}', 'YourController@action')->where('params', '(.*)');
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The 'routeName' is also created dynamically so I do not want to define the route one by one by hardcoding it in the route because it can be a lot.

Comment: after testing your solution, I change the `routeName` to a variable `{slug}` so I do not have to define the route name one by one

Comment: Yes. If you define routeName as {slug} then it's name become dynamic.

Comment: In best practice, you should fix your routeName while making apis. Therefore in larger applications, you can easily debug it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this trick

```
Route::get('{pageLink}/{otherParams?}', 'IndexController@get')->where('otherParams', '(.*)');
```

You should put it on the end of routes.php file as it is like a 'catch all' route.

```
class IndexController extends BaseController {

    public function get($pageLink, $otherParams = null)
    {
        if($otherParams) 
        {
            $otherParams = explode('/', $otherParams);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works as what I want. To handle any method I changed from get to any.